# Format date direct from entity

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am using Symfony3 with doctrine and my question is:

Is possible after getQuery in query builder get results with attribute which has formatted date?

I have attr in entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="terminFrom", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $terminFrom;
```

My try - set format in getter:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTerminFrom()
{
    return $this->terminFrom->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

But still after getQuery i have \DateTime object in this attribute.

I don't understand - attributes in entity are private so getters must be called... or?

Comment: Nope.  Doctrine uses reflection to directly access your private/protected properties.  Not even the constructor is used.

Comment: However, when you access to `getTerminFrom()` method this one should return a formated string from current datetime instance correctly.

Comment: @yceruto yes, but i this data sending directly to json response - so i must create loop over and define each variable terminFrom?

Comment: Then you likely need a "GetSetMethodNormalizer" to convert it to json through getters.

Comment: Have you looked at the serializer component?  It's probably the way to go for anything that might become non-trivial.  I confess that your questions and code do not make sense to me.  I do know how Doctrine works so my first comment stands.  But if you call getTerminFrom then you should get a formatted data string.  I think you meant to show the set function.  And how this ties into json is a big question.

Comment: @LajdákMarek: Have you considered using a custom repository method which would give you a preprocessed result for your query? Or try a custom hydrator which inherits your preferred standard hydrator, but applies some filters afterwards.